# What does this page represent?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, site-collection, managed-metadata

I am sure this is a really simple question, but can anyone tell me what this page represents?

[image: welcome to your publishing site]

I know it is not my site collection page nor is it central administration. The reason I am asking is because I am creating my content types and sites column and managed meta data at this page level but they do not seem to be appearing on my site collection or any of its sub sites. I understand that if content types, site columns, & Managed Meta Data are created in central administration then would be available to any site in my SharePoint environment. I do not have access to central administration. I thought this was a level in between central administration and my site collection. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default page of a publishing site. The content you see is in web parts, which can easily be removed. All of the links also exist in site settings, so this page is just trying to be helpful and present links for the most common tasks on a publishing site.

Comment: this publishing site is called http://sharepointdev/pages/default...                       i have a site collection called http://sharepointdev/sites/sandbox...(i know this cause in site settings i have "site collection adminstration")               i am currently creating my content types, site columns, & managed meta data at http://sharepointdev/pages/default, my question is why are the content types not showing up in the content types of http://sharepointdev/sites/sandbox

Comment: looks like you are stuck in two different site collection. Sharepointdev/ is the root level site collection and /site/sandbox is 2nd site collection....if you create the content type in root level then it will be there for 2nd site colelction you need to create on /sites/sanbox....if you configure the MMS then both site collection can access it...